# how can i restore nautilus theme after installing multiple desktop environments along with unity

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments

as you can see here, the icons seem bigger than usual and window frame which included menus such as file are no longer there

[image]

Comment: i have already tried apt install --reinstall nautilus

Answer (score 0):

Install Unity Tweak Tool :

`sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`

Then open it from Dash by searching for Unity Tweak Tool, then go to themes icon, then click it, then change selection to "ambience". Should fix.

Comment: i already tried doing so and nothing has changed,